# Error: Project with > path ':react-native-fbsdk' could not be found in root project

Tags: react-native

I am trying to execute react native code on android environment so i am getting this type of error:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AMapps'. > Project with
>   path ':react-native-fbsdk' could not be found in root project
>   'AMapps'.  * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: well, it cant find your root. so its possible you did something wrong in your code. can you post your code?

Comment: thanks and i got solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following code on the file `android/settings.gradle`.

```
include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
```